# Proving that $8^n-2^n$ is a multiple of $6$ for all $n\geq 0$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

I have the following induction problem:

> $8^n-2^n$ is a multiple of $6$ for all integers $n\geq 0$.

So far this is what I've done:

**Base case:** $n = 0$

$8^0-2^0 = 6$

$1 - 1 = 6$

$0 = 6$

This means that it's a multiple of $6$.

Assume $n = k\colon 8^k - 2^k = 6m$

Where I'm getting stuck now is factoring out $8^k - 2^k = 6m$. The example I'm following on YouTube was $6^k + 4 = 5m$, which factored out nicely to $(5m-4) \cdot 6 + 4$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the induction step a bit. You are to assume it's true for some $k$, and now show it's true for $k+1$.

Comment: $8^0-6^0$ doesn't equal 6. You might want to be more explicit.

Comment: @avid19 Aren't I supposed to check if that answer is divisible by 6? From the video I was watching it said as long as the answer is divisible by the number you're working with it would be okay.

Comment: And how are you guys actually typing out the exponents? I can't seem to use the HTML tags in the comments.

Comment: You just use a "^"  so "x^y" = $x^y$

Comment: @Brenton Alright, so I've gotten the LHS to equal 8^k+1 - 2^k+1 but I can't seem to figure out how to get the RHS.

Comment: You're supposed to check if $8^0-6^0$ is divisible by $6$, you are correct. This means that there exists some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $8^0-6^0=6k$. You just said that $0=6$ which is not true at all. @Matt

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq 0$, let $S(n)$ denote the statement
$$
S(n) : 6 \mid (8^n-2^n)\Longleftrightarrow 8^n-2^n=6m, m\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

**Base case ($n=0$):** $S(0)$ says that $6\mid (8^0-2^0)$, and this is true.

**Inductive step:** Fix some $k\geq 0$ and assume that $S(k)$ is true where
$$
S(k) : 6\mid (8^k-2^k)\Longleftrightarrow 8^k-2^k=6\ell, \ell\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
To be shown is that $S(k+1)$ follows where
$$
S(k+1) : 6\mid (8^{k+1}-2^{k+1})\Longleftrightarrow 8^{k+1}-2^{k+1}=6\eta, \eta\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Beginning with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
8^{k+1}-2^{k+1} &= 8\cdot 8^k-2\cdot 2^k\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&= 8(8^k-2^k)+6\cdot 2^k\tag{rearrange}\\[0.5em]
&= 8(6\ell)+6\cdot 2^k\tag{by $S(k)$, the ind. hyp.}\\[0.5em]
&= 6(8\ell+2^k)\tag{factor out $6$}\\[0.5em]
&= 6\eta,\tag{$\eta=8\ell+2^k; \eta\in\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

Thus, by mathematical induction, the statement $S(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 0$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your base case should be $0=6\times0$, thus it is a multiple of $6$.

Now as @Brenton said, our inductive step is as follows:

Assume $6$ divides $8^k-2^k$, for some $k$ (we write this $6\mid8^k-2^k$).

We want to show that $6\mid8^{k+1}-2^{k+1}$, using this assumption.

Ok so $$6\mid8^k-2^k$$ so $$6\mid8(8^k-2^k)=8^{k+1}-8\times2^k=8^{k+1}-4\times2^{k+1}$$

Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: Question: What does the | mean? Is that a substitute for =?

Comment: It means "divides". That is, $6|24$ reads "6 divides 24", or equivalently, 24 is divisible by 6.

Comment: Small point, but $6|24$ doesn't really look right does it? I'd suggest using `\mid` in the future. For example, $6\mid 24$ (using `$6\mid 24$`) looks a lot better than $6|24$ doesn't it?

Answer (score -1):

By the binomial theorem, $8^n=(6+2)^n=6a+2^n$.

Induction is used to prove the binomial theorem.